# Zotero: adding lookup engine

Tags: zotero

I just deleted the Pubget Article Lookup engine from Zotero by accident. How can I add it back? I visited the http://puget.com website but the "add" button does not appear in my Locate menu as suggested in the instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These settings seem to be stored in the file:

> ~/.zotero/zotero/_your_profile_name_here_/zotero/locate/engines.json

I was able to restore the entry by picking a copy of this file, e.g. from GitHub:

> wget -O ~/.zotero/zotero/_your_profile_name_here_/zotero/locate/engines.json https://raw.github.com/robinpaulson/impero/master/engines.json

Note: I assume a *nix-systems, but I guess it should work similarly on Windows-systems.